# no visible @interface for nsmutableurlrequest declares the selector sethttpbody

Tags: ios

[this is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3xiU.png)[I searched for solution of this but did not get any solution. why it shows me an error displayed in screenshot. please help me.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gourmet7.com/auth"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7wwF.png)

Comment: i am new in ios. please give me a solution i am using xcode 7.2

Comment: What have yout tried so far?

Comment: i want to make post request. i cant understand whats went wrong. @Genzotto did you get my question.

Comment: Can you post your source code at least?

Comment: this is my first question on stack overflow, please understand.

Comment: @ Genzotto have you seen my source code i attached screenshot also please check it

Comment: Your code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only be a wild guess, but as your code compiles just fine, I think you're targeting some iOS version lower than 8.0.

Unfortunately, the `HTTPBody` property is only available since 8.0. So you either have to raise the minimum iOS version to at least 8.0 or use another mechanism.